# \RequirePackage with path fails to locate latex style file

Tags: packages

I am using

```
\RequirePackage{./expkv/expkv-opt,./expkv/expkv-def}

But getting 

/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex fredholm.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./fredholm.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-20>
(/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(./gungadin.sty (./expkv/expkv-opt.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `./expkv/expkv-opt',
               but the package provides `expkv-opt'.
```

Comment: there is no failure, you only get a rather harmless warning.

Comment: It works here, but the argument to `\RequirePackage` is supposed to be a _name_, not a _path_: use `TEXINPUTS` or similar to make the files 'findable'.

Comment: It is name, the path is `./expkv/` whilst the name is `expkv-opt`.  Thought that one can include a path when the style files are put into a directory somewhere.

Comment: @Ephram I mean that you should have `\RequirePackage{expkv-opt}`, with any path part handled by `kpsewhich`

Comment: There is no failure then, thank you.  The document is being made correctly.

Comment: Do not know about `kpsewhich`.  Could you explain what's needed exactly?

Comment: The warning is intended to discourage you from using a path here, the argument should be a name not a file path. use `expkv-opt` delete your local `./expkv` directory and use the standard version of the package that is in texlive. Using a local version masks the standard version so you will not get any bug fixes or updates.

Comment: I see.  Was doing that way, when I was still with the old Tex Live 2017.  Did not know that `expkv` is provided by Tex Live 2022.

Comment: But I still need to know how to set the correct path for accessing my own style files.

Comment: just put your own files in `~/texmf/tex/latex` and latex will find them, you don't need to put non-portable local paths in your document. But for standard texlive packages as you show here.  do not have local copies at all.

Comment: but (as you found) using a local copy was also wrong in texlive 2017, the errors were different but the basic issue the same, the files were inconsistent with installed code.

Comment: I am still developing my style files.  Regarding developing style files, could tex all using other local directory besides `~/texmf/tex/latex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error. It is as it says in the text you quoted, a warning. The file has been read.

That said, the warning is intended to discourage you from using a path here, the argument should be a name not a file path. Use `\usepackage{expkv-opt}` delete your local `./expkv` directory and use the standard version of the package that is in texlive. Using a local version masks the standard version so you will not get any bug fixes or updates.

Unrelated but you should make sure your path is correct and then use

```
pdflatex fredholm.tex
```

not

```
/home/Opstk/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex fredholm.tex
```

If you use a full path to the executable then things will seem to work but on more complicated packages you will get strange version mis-match failures. If, for example,  pdflatex calls out to epstopdf, or makindex or any other internal system call, it will pick up the command in your path which may not match the version of pdftex that you are using if you call it by full path name as here.

Comment: The problem is that I have an old Tex Live installed.  What should I do?

Comment: @Ephram haven't you already asked multiple questions about insalling tl2022 ??? just set your PATH as described in your last question.

Comment: True.  Still, my installation is a bit of a hack at this time.

Comment: Have figured out what happened.  Was using an old xterm where the updated `.bashrc` was not sourced yet.

Comment: @Ephram as you were told on the last question it is better to use .profile or .bash_profile than .bashrc and to log out then log in, then that would not have happened

Comment: Am working on it.  Thank you so very much.

Comment: Have made the `.bash_profile` with the update to `PATH`.  But I am still having the problem that `pdflatex fredholm.tex` calls `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`.

Comment: @Ephram then you have set the wrong path or set it at the wrong place, but that is all only loosely on topic here, it's a gneral linux setup qustion how to set environment variables, if you type `echo $PATH` is your 2022 directory in the path at all? if made a new file `.bash_profile` then that almost certainly won't work. You need to set the path in the setup file that you are using. That may be .bash_profile or .profile or .session or other possibilities depending how your account set up. If your login shell is not bash then .bash_profile _definitely_ won't be used. But this is off topic.

Comment: No, the directory path does not show as expected.

Comment: I made a new `.bash_profile` file with the Tex Live path appended to `PATH`.  The command `echo $PATH` does not show the new Tex Live directory.

Comment: as I said above if you didn't already have a .bash_profile your login is probably configured to read a different file, perhaps .profile but this is just about your linux setup it is really off topic here, and not really anything we can help you with remotely. in your home directory do `ls .*` and see what  dot files you have. Again as I have already said if your login shell is not bash then  .bash_profile certainly won't be used.

Comment: My login shell is bash.